# TikZ: Understanding the usage of calc library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

For the following MWE, I need to place block `(yaw) {C}` midway between (1) the middle point between `(output)` and `(integrator)` (2) and `(sum2)`.

So, how can I correct this syntax `\node [block] (yaw) at ([yshift=-2cm]$(integrator)+0.5*{(output)-(integrator)}!0.5!(sum2)$) {C};` to make it work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style= {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',align=center]
     \node [sum] (sum2) {};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of sum2](ractuator){$\frac{2}{s+2}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of ractuator,] (vdynamics) {$\frac{-0.125(s+0.437)}{(s+1.29)(s+0.193)}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of vdynamics,] (integrator) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
    \node [output, right = 1.5cm of integrator] (output) {};
    \node [block] (yaw) at ([yshift=-2cm]$(integrator)+0.5*{(output)-(integrator)}!0.5!(sum2)$) {C};
    %
    \draw [->] (ractuator) -- (vdynamics);
    \draw [->] (vdynamics) -- (integrator);
    \draw [->] (integrator) -- node[name=heading]{$\Psi(s)$} (output);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Additionally, is it possible to create a new node using `\node [tmp, below = 2cm of ($(output)!0.5!(integrator)$) ] (tmp1) {};` without creating auxiliary nodes/coordinates?

Comment: Hey! Did `($.25*(output)+.25*(integrator)+.5*(sum2)$)` work for you?

Comment: @Vinzza It does. But, why does my approach not work?

Comment: Comments do not allow enough characters, so I have replied with an answer! I hope it will help you! :)

Comment: Your approach does not work because you try to use `{` and `}` where you should use `($` and `$)`. Try `($(0,-2cm)+(integrator)+0.5*($(output)-(integrator)$)!0.5!(sum2)$)`  to have something that does not throw an error. However, from your description in words I think you want `\node [block] (yaw) at 
 ($(0,-2cm)+($(output)!0.5!(integrator)$)!0.5!(sum2)$) {C};`, yet this can be done without `calc`: `\node [block] (yaw) at 
 ([yshift=-2cm]barycentric cs:output=1,integrator=1,sum2=2) {C};`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how complex expression can be understood by `calc` but instead of trying to understand how to write such expression, I think it's easier to use an auxiliar coordinate and solve the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style= {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',align=center]
     \node [sum] (sum2) {};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of sum2](ractuator){$\frac{2}{s+2}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of ractuator,] (vdynamics) {$\frac{-0.125(s+0.437)}{(s+1.29)(s+0.193)}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of vdynamics,] (integrator) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
    \node [output, right = 1.5cm of integrator] (output) {};
    \coordinate (aux) at ($(integrator.east)!.5!(output)$);
    \node [block] (yaw) at ([yshift=-2cm]$(aux)!0.5!(sum2)$) {C};
    \draw (aux) |- (yaw);
    \draw (yaw)-|(sum2);
    %
    \draw [->] (ractuator) -- (vdynamics);
    \draw [->] (vdynamics) -- (integrator);
    \draw [->] (integrator) -- node[name=heading]{$\Psi(s)$} (output);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. For my question edit, can I make a new node using this syntax `\node [tmp, below = 2cm of ($(output)!0.5!(integrator)$) ] (tmp1) {};`?

Comment: @Diaa Something like `\node [block, yshift=-2cm] (yaw) at ($(aux)!.5!(sum2)$) {C};` works for me. Instead of `yshift` you could also use `below=2cm` but with a different result. The `calc` expression in `positioning` option didn't work for me.

Comment: @Diaa In any case I don't see the problem in using auxiliary coordinates/nodes. What's wrong with them?

Comment: Nothing wrong; I just want to teach myself how to reduce my code :)

Answer (score 6):

Your approach does not work because you try to use `{` and `}` where you should use `($` and `$)`.  You can definitely do that without auxiliary coordinates and actually even without `calc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style= {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',align=center]
     \node [sum] (sum2) {};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of sum2](ractuator){$\frac{2}{s+2}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of ractuator,] (vdynamics) {$\frac{-0.125(s+0.437)}{(s+1.29)(s+0.193)}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of vdynamics,] (integrator) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
    \node [output, right = 1.5cm of integrator] (output) {};
    \node [block] (yaw) at 
    ($(0,-2cm)+($(output)!0.5!(integrator)$)!0.5!(sum2)$) {C};
    %
    \draw [->] (ractuator) -- (vdynamics);
    \draw [->] (vdynamics) -- (integrator);
    \draw [->] (integrator) -- node[name=heading]{$\Psi(s)$} (output)
    coordinate[midway] (aux);
    \draw (aux) |- (yaw) -| (sum2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',align=center]
     \node [sum] (sum2) {};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of sum2](ractuator){$\frac{2}{s+2}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of ractuator,] (vdynamics) {$\frac{-0.125(s+0.437)}{(s+1.29)(s+0.193)}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of vdynamics,] (integrator) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
    \node [output, right = 1.5cm of integrator] (output) {};
    \node [block] (yaw) at 
    ([yshift=-2cm]barycentric cs:output=1,integrator=1,sum2=2) {C};
    %
    \draw [->] (ractuator) -- (vdynamics);
    \draw [->] (vdynamics) -- (integrator);
    \draw [->] (integrator) -- node[name=heading]{$\Psi(s)$} (output)
    coordinate[midway] (aux);
    \draw (aux) |- (yaw) -| (sum2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but could you tell me where I can find more explanation on this line `([yshift=-2cm] barycentric cs:output=1,integrator=1,sum2=2)`?

Comment: @Diaa Section 13.2.2 Barycentric Systems of the pgfmanual. Come on, it only has 1161 pages. (Just kidding! ;-)

Comment: XD. If you don't mind, I have off-topic question: when saying `node distance = 2 cm`, it measures this distance between the nodes centers. Is it possible to make this distance imply the spacing between `(left node.east)` and `(right node.west)` instead?

Comment: @Diaa I am not sure I agree with your statement. You are already loading `positioning`, in which case the distances are measured between the node boundaries (modulo a very tiny bit of fine print). Try e.g. `\node [block, right=of sum2](ractuator){$\frac{2}{s+2}$};` in your settings. Then you will see that the distance between the node boundaries, and not centers, is 2cm, which is the value of `node distance` in your code.

Comment: I tried drawing a new node `\node [block, above of = yaw, draw=none, node distance=1mm] {Yaw Rate\\Sensor};` and the result is two overlapping nodes as seen [here](https://imgur.com/dVP9QO6).

Comment: @Diaa This is because you are not using the positioning syntax. Try `\node [block, above=of  yaw, draw=none, node distance=1mm] {Yaw Rate\\Sensor};` where crucially the `=` is before `of`, which is what I mean by "positioning syntax". This can be shortened `\node [block, above=1mm of  yaw, draw=none] {Yaw Rate\\Sensor};`.

Comment: I have been doing it wrong for so long time :\. I am so grateful for your patience, and I found that `\node [block, above = of yaw, draw=none, node distance = 0mm] {Yaw Rate\\Sensor};` doesn't override the global setting of `node distance` in tikzpicture options. However, `\node [block, above = 0mm of yaw, draw=none] {Yaw Rate\\Sensor};` overrides successfully the global setting of `node distance`, and I am too lazy to make a MWE for this question :) Many thanks for your help again

Answer (score 5):

Here, to simplify the code, I'll replace `(integrator)` with `(A)`, `(output)` with `(B)` and `(sum2)` with `(C)`.
There is two things not right with
`($ (A) + 0.5*{ (B)-(A) }!0.5!(C) $)`.

- First, I don't think you can use `{}`, with the calc package, for the coordinate part. For me, it only works for with scalar. So `($ {2+2}*(A) $)` will compute, but not `($ 2*{(A)+(B)} $)` (or am I wrong?)
- The second thing is that this formula doesn't seem to correspond to the point you want.
  I kind of get that you want to start from (A), "move" to the middle of [AB] and continue like that, but you mix relative (B-A) and absolute positioning (C).
  One right formula would have been `($ { (A) + 0.5*{(B)-(A)} }!0.5!(C) $)`.
  But because tikz can't do the computation, you'll have to give the expanded formula: `($ .25*(A) + .25*(B) + .5*(C)$)`.

One other way to do it is `($ (A) !.5! (B) !.5! (C) $)`. Here, we take the middle of (A) and (B), and then the middle of the result and (C).

I hope this will answer your interrogations!

You can test the three solutions here (the last one with temporary coordinate):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1]

  \draw[black!10] (0,0) grid (4,4);
  \node (A) at (1,1) {A};
  \node (B) at (3,1) {B};
  \node (C) at (2,3) {C};

  %% 1
  \draw[red] ($ (A) !.5! (B) !.5! (C) $) circle (.05);
  %% 2
  \draw[orange] ($ .25*(A) + .25*(B) + .5*(C) $) circle (.1);
  %% 3
  \coordinate (foo) at ($ (A) !.5! (B) $);
  \draw[yellow] ($ (foo) !.5! (C) $) circle (.15);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't interrogate :)

Answer (score 5):

The `calc` library allows you to apply `Parway Modifiers` repeatedly. Thus, the following syntax

```
($(integrator)!.5!!(output)!0.5!(sum2)$)
```

does the following:

- pgf calculates the middle of `(integrator)` and `(output)`
- then calculates the middle of this last calculated point and the next one `(sum2)`

We can continue like this as many times as we want.

Here is for example page 144 of the manual 3.0.1a modified by adding two more points.

[image: exemple]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
%first node
\draw[densely dotted] (0,0) -- (3,2);
\node[] at ($(0,0)!.3!(3,2)$) {1};
%second node
\draw[densely dotted] ($(0,0)!.3!(3,2)$) -- (3,0);
\node[] at ($(0,0)!.3!(3,2)!.7!(3,0)$){2};

%third node
\draw[densely dotted] ($(0,0)!.3!(3,2)!.7!(3,0)$)--(3,2);
\node[]at ($(0,0)!.3!(3,2)!.7!(3,0)!.6!(3,2)$) {3};

%fourth node
\draw[densely dotted] ($(0,0)!.3!(3,2)!.7!(3,0)!.6!(3,2)$)--(0,2);
\node[]at ($(0,0)!.3!(3,2)!.7!(3,0)!.6!(3,2)!.5!(0,2)$) {4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this does not simplify the writing of the code. The use of an auxiliary point as @Ignasi did is therefore more elegant.

### Updated just for fun: A complete solution with the `calc` library

And without using `yshift=-2cm` and without intermediate point *(It's really complicated and unreadable!)*

```
\draw (sum2)|-($(integrator)!.5!(output)!0.5!(sum2)!2cm!90:(sum2)$)node[block]{C}-|($(integrator)!.5!(output)$);
```

But which places the point in the same place with the syntax indicated in the manual 3.0.1a p143, i quote:

> The general meaning of `<a>!<factor>!<angle>:<b>` is “First, consider
>   the line from `<a>` to `<b>`. Then rotate this line by `<angle>` around the
>   point `<a>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style= {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',align=center]
     \node [sum] (sum2) {};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of sum2](ractuator){$\frac{2}{s+2}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of ractuator,] (vdynamics) {$\frac{-0.125(s+0.437)}{(s+1.29)(s+0.193)}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of vdynamics,] (integrator) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
    \node [output, right = 1.5cm of integrator] (output) {};
    \draw (sum2)|-($(integrator)!.5!(output)!0.5!(sum2)!2cm!90:(sum2)$)node[block]{C}-|($(integrator)!.5!(output)$);
    \draw [->] (ractuator) -- (vdynamics);
    \draw [->] (vdynamics) -- (integrator);
    \draw [->] (integrator) -- node[name=heading]{$\Psi(s)$} (output);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Old answer:

**Nevertheless**, here is a solution that includes a series of `Parway Modifiers`.

[image: soluce]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style= {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',align=center]
     \node [sum] (sum2) {};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of sum2](ractuator){$\frac{2}{s+2}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of ractuator,] (vdynamics) {$\frac{-0.125(s+0.437)}{(s+1.29)(s+0.193)}$};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of vdynamics,] (integrator) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
    \node [output, right = 1.5cm of integrator] (output) {};
    \draw (sum2)|-([yshift=-2cm]$(integrator)!.5!(output)!0.5!(sum2)$)node[block]{C}-|($(integrator)!.5!(output)$);

    \draw [->] (ractuator) -- (vdynamics);
    \draw [->] (vdynamics) -- (integrator);
    \draw [->] (integrator) -- node[name=heading]{$\Psi(s)$} (output);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Answer (score 3):

one way how to reduce your code:

- use tikz library`chains` placement nodes in chain and draw lines between them by macro `join`
- node "c" in feedback simple pace below of node `vdynamics`
- put coordinates in image directly and not via nodes
- coordinates can contain labels, exploit this for label `$\Psi$`
- define nodes distance only ones and than use it all all nodes positioning

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz,nccmath,amssymb}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                  calc, chains,
                  positioning,
                  shapes}

  \begin{document}

  \tikzset{
    block/.style  = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum size=3em,
                     on chain, join=by ->},
      sum/.style  = {draw, fill=white, circle},
  }
  \makeatletter
  \tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}   % <--- for dicountinue of jon macro
  \makeatother

      \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance = 0.5cm and 1cm,
        start chain = going right,
                  > = latex']
  \coordinate (in);
  \node [sum,right=of in, on chain] (sum2)    {};
  \node [block]   (ractuator)     {$\mfrac{2}{s+2}$};
  \node [block]   (vdynamics)     {$\mfrac{-0.125(s+0.437)}{(s+1.29)(s+0.193)}$};
  \node [block]   (integrator)    {$\mfrac{1}{s}$};
  \coordinate[right=of integrator] (out)      {};
  \node [block, suspend join,
         below = of vdynamics]  (yaw) {C};
      %
  \draw[->]   (in) -- (sum2);
  \draw[->]   (integrator) -- coordinate[label=$\Psi(s)$] (psi) (out);
  \draw[->]   (psi) |- (yaw);
  \draw[->]   (yaw) -| (sum2);
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

off-topic: for fraction is used `\mfrac` (medium sized fraction) defined in the `nccmath` package